# I'm getting error "Public key for jenkins-2.232-1.1.noarch.rpm is not installed" while installing Jenkins on AWS EC2

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

I'm installing Jenkins on AWS EC2 CentOS instance.
I'm following this tutorial for installation - https://medium.com/@itsmattburgess/installing-jenkins-on-amazon-linux-16aaa02c369c.
I'm getting the below error while installing:

```
Downloading packages:
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/jenkins/packages/jenkins-2.232-1.1.noarch.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID 45f2c3d5: NOKEY:00 ETA
Public key for jenkins-2.232-1.1.noarch.rpm is not installed
jenkins-2.232-1.1.noarch.rpm | 63 MB 00:01:49
```

[image]

Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: Did you run this command already?
`sudo rpm --import http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key`
This was mentioned in the guide you are using.

Answer (score 82):

Jenkins is changing their signing keys again.
Beginning with LTS `2.387.2` and weekly `2.397`, releases will be signed with a new GPG key.

The correct public key can be found on the page for [Jenkins Redhat Packages](https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/) and in [Jenkins installation handbook](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#red-hat-centos). Just run the command below to import it:

- [Long Term Support release](https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/):

  ```bash
  sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key
  ```
- [Weekly release](https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/):

  ```bash
  sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.io-2023.key
  ```

See Jenkins Blog posts for details:

- [Jenkins 2.397 and 2.387.2: New Linux Repository Signing Keys](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2023/03/27/repository-signing-keys-changing/)
- [Jenkins 2.235.3: New Linux Repository Signing Keys](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/07/27/repository-signing-keys-changing/)

Comment: this helped me! thanks a lot

Comment: Debian/Ubuntu
`wget -qO - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | apt-key add -`
Red Hat/CentOS
`rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key`

Blog post https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/07/27/repository-signing-keys-changing/

Comment: worked for me thank you so much

Answer (score 19):

**Updated:** They've updated their key URL to the following - import this key as part of the setup instead and the `yum install` call should function without issues and not require disabling the gpg check:

https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.io.key

---

*Original answer:* I've also been hitting this.  The team has apparently updated their key, but haven't updated the docs or published the new public key component and the one located at http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key isn't valid any longer.  For now you can run a `yum install` with GPG check disabled just to get past the initial install Jenkins:

```
yum install jenkins --nogpgcheck
```

Once they've published the new public key, you'll want to import it with the `rpm --import [url]` call per usual so that `yum update` will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved. Instead of the command "sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins.repo" i used "sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
"and it was working. Than's every for viewing my question and taking time to answer it.